# how to write jpa query for joining multiple tables

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I need to build the following query in one entity class by joining multiple tables.

```
SELECT t1.column_id_1
  FROM table1 t1,
       Table2 t2,
       Table3 t3,
       Table4 t4,
       Table5 t5
WHERE     t1.COLUMN_ID_1 = t2. COLUMN _ID_1
       AND t2.COLUMN_ID_2 = t3. COLUMN_ID_2
       AND t3.COLUMN_ID_3 = t4. COLUMN_ID_3
       AND t4.COLUMN_ID_4 = t5. COLUMN_ID_4
```

Please share some ideas

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your model is mapped to database. For example, if T1 is mapped to `A` class and T2 is mapped to `B` class and `A` is declared somehow like that:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "t1")
public class A {
    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "COLUMN_ID_1")
    private B b;
}

@Entity @Table(name = "t2")
public class B {
    @Id @Column(name = "COLUMN_ID_1)
    private Integer id;
}
```

Then in JPQL you just write

```
select b.id
from A a
join a.b as b
```

and so on for another tables.

Comment: can we do it using secondaryTables annotaion?

Comment: Yes, you can. And there are many other ways depending on your needs.

Comment: can u share how to do it using secondary tables. I want to add all the mapping inside the table1 entity. can i do that

Comment: [@SecondaryTables](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTables.html)?